# C# Xaml - Use Custom Class - Works programatically but not in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm pretty new with Xaml and i'm facing an issue . I want to use FontAwesome Icons in my app and after following a tutorial , i can use the icons programmatically (Code Below) .

```
Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new FontIcon(FontIcon.Icon.Globe) {TextColor=Color.Red }
                  },
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
```

However , when i try to implement this in Xaml - it crashes my app.

Code for Shared class extending label :

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace myApp.Fonts
{
    public class FontIcon : Label
    {
        public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";

        public FontIcon(string faIcon = null)
        {
            FontFamily = Typeface;  
            Text = faIcon;
        }

        public static class Icon
        {
            public static readonly string Gear = "";
            public static readonly string Globe = "\uf000";
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml code ...Note that i'm already using the xmlns:local for another class

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myApp.TestPage"
             xmlns:ctt="clr-namespace:myApp.Fonts">


<ctt:FontIcon  FontIcon ="\uf000" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

I'm guessing the issue is with this line :

```
<ctt:FontIcon  FontIcon ="\uf000" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

I'm not sure how to access that class via xaml  or if its even possible to use xlmns:ctt

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------

I used debug and this is the actual error :

System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type myApp.Fonts.FontIcon

Edit 2 :

I did this :

```
public FAIcon()
        {

        }
```

And in xaml :

```
<custom:FAIcon FontFamily = "Typeface" Text = "\uf000" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

The app doesn't crash now but it displays the plain text instead of the icon

This is my android renderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FontIcon), typeof(FARenderer))]

namespace myApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class FARenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, FontIcon.Typeface + ".ttf");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: <ctt:FontIcon  FontIcon ="\uf000" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

Comment: Its crashing my app . myApp.Droid has stopped working - i'm trying to debug to see the actual error

Comment: why do you need a custom control if all your are doing is setting the Text and FontFamily properties?

Comment: @MikeT - System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type myApp.Fonts.FontIcon

Comment: XAML requires a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Jimmy any object used in XAML must have an Empty Constructor so `public FontIcon(){...}`you would then set the properties in the elements as `VerticalOptions="Center"`

Comment: @MikeT  - updated my answer - it works with empty contructor but does not display the icon - just the plain text

Comment: @Jason -  updated my answer - it works with empty contructor but does not display the icon - just the plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you always want to use FontAwesome, set it in your constructor:

```
public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";

public FAIcon()
{
  FontFamily = TypeFace;
}
```

don't do this in your XAML, it just sets the FontFamily to "TypeFace" which is not what you want

```
<custom:FAIcon FontFamily = "Typeface" ...
```

Comment: Thanks - I did both but its still displaying the plain text instead of the icon .Any idea what the issue is ?

Comment: Thanks - i added an x:Name in the Xaml ..and in my cs file - i set the text - its working now :)